# Nginx subdomain proxy pass order

Tags: nginx

I have two apps running on ports `3000` and `3030`.

mydomain.com should point to 127.0.0.1:3000 while app.mydomain.com should point to 127.0.0.1:3030.

Using the configuration below, app.mydomain.com displays the app running on port 3000 instead of 3030. If I change the order, it's vice versa.

The `sites-available/default` file:

```
# Redirect to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Landing page
server {
    listen 443;

    server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}

# App
server {
    listen 443;

    server_name app.mydomain.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3030;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was that I am using an IDN domain (with the character **ä**). I failed to mention this in the question.

Changing the `server_names` to the punycode version solved the issue.